# How to load a binary tree from LeetCode input format in my own IDE

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I am currently doing BST code challenges on LeetCode but I prefer doing them in my own IDE. I am using IntelliJ IDEA. Just as an example of such code challenges, there is this LeetCode question for finding the [Maximum Path Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/):

> A path in a binary tree is a sequence of nodes where each pair of adjacent nodes in the sequence has an edge connecting them. A node can only appear in the sequence at most once. Note that the path does not need to pass through the root.
>
> The path sum of a path is the sum of the node's values in the path.
>
> Given the `root` of a binary tree, *return the maximum path sum of any non-empty path.*

My code is as follows:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right

class Solution(object):
    def maxPathSum(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: int
        """

        def maxSum(root, max_sum=0):
            if root is None:
                return max_sum

            left_root = root.left.val
            right_root = root.right.val
            final_sum = left_root + right_root + root.val
            if final_sum > max_sum:
                max_sum = final_sum
                maxSum(root, max_sum)

        return maxSum(root)


print(Solution().maxPathSum(root=[-10, 9, 20, None, None, 15, 7]))
```

I know there are mistakes in my code, but I can't test them out, since I am used to my Tree Nodes input to be like so:

```
test_tree_node = BST(20)
test_tree_node.insert(5)
test_tree_node.insert(23)
```

The input (test-cases) given in LeetCode are in an array format, which they transform automatically into a `TreeNode` instance. I used their example of `[-10, 9, 20, None, None, 15, 7]` as input in my IDE, but that obviously doesn't work, as it is not a `TreeNode`. This input represents the following tree (values given in level order):

```
         -10 
        /   \
       9     20
            /  \
          15    7
```

How could to test my code with such inputs, so that `root.left` and `root.right` works, etc.

---

For the BST that I mentioned above, it looks like this:

````
class BST:
    def __init__(self, value, depth=1):
        self.value = value
        self.depth = depth
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert(self, value):
        if value < self.value:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = BinarySearchTree(value=value, depth=self.depth + 1)
                print(f'Tree node {value} added to the left of {self.value} at depth {self.depth + 1}')
            else:
                self.left.insert(value)
        else:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = BinarySearchTree(value=value, depth=self.depth + 1)
                print(f'Tree node {value} added to the right of {self.value} at depth {self.depth + 1}')
            else:
                self.right.insert(value)

    def get_node_by_value(self, value):
        if value == self.value:
            return self
        elif self.left and value < self.value:
            return self.left.get_node_by_value(value)
        elif self.right and value >= self.value:
            return self.right.get_node_by_value(value)
        else:
            return None

    def depth_first_traversal(self):
        if self.left is not None:
            self.left.depth_first_traversal()
        print(f'Depth={self.depth}, Value={self.value}')
        if self.right is not None:
            self.right.depth_first_traversal()
```
````

Comment: Let's see how your BST class is defined

Comment: "The input (test-cases) given in leet code are an array. What library would I import to be able to test them? (So that root.left and root.right works etc)." - You would not use a library. You would use **the BST class that you created**, by **creating a BST from** the values in the list (we don't call them "arrays"). In order to do this, you need to understand *how* the values in the list *represent* a BST (i.e., how they tell you the shape of the BST and what values appear and where). We cannot tell you this, because you find out by **reading the problem statement**.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Oh, I was just wondering if there are any code written to simplify when testing the list which appears in the format [root node, left node, right node etc]. Obviously it is different for every case which I now realises makes it harder to write a library (like deque and heaps library). Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, the code challenge you are looking at is not a "BST question" as you call it: it is not giving you a binary *search* tree nor is it intended to be one, but just a binary tree, so your `BST` class is mostly irrelevant here.

The only class you need to work with here, is the `TreeNode` class, which is given in the comment section at the top:

```
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

So the first thing to do in your IDE is to uncomment it, so that you have the above class defined.

Now to the main question: the format used by LeetCode is a JSON-like input which looks like a list in Python, but is actually a text format (note how it uses `null` and not `None`). The LeetCode platform converts this text input to a (nested) instance of `TreeNode` before your function is called. This format is explained on the [LeetCode website](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011883654-What-does-1-null-2-3-mean-in-binary-tree-representation-):

> The input `[1,null,2,3]` represents the serialized format of a binary tree using level order traversal, where `null` signifies a path terminator where no node exists below.

To mimic that process based on a Python list as input, you could make use of this function:

```
def to_binary_tree(items):
    if not items:
        return None

    it = iter(items)
    root = TreeNode(next(it))
    q = [root]
    for node in q:
        val = next(it, None)
        if val is not None:
            node.left = TreeNode(val)
            q.append(node.left)
        val = next(it, None)
        if val is not None:
            node.right = TreeNode(val)
            q.append(node.right)
    return root
```

Now you can run your solution code by doing this:

```
lst = [-10, 9, 20, None, None, 15, 7]
root = to_binary_tree(lst)
print(Solution().maxPathSum(root))
```

Finally, your `maxSum` function is not doing the right thing. The only thing it ever does is summing up the values of three nodes: that of the root, and its two direct children. The recursive call will make that same calculation a second time and will conclude it is not an improvement and then return `None` (implicitly). And so `maxPathSum` will return `None`.

Your code will get a run time error if the root does not have two children.

As your question was about the conversion of a list to a tree, I will leave this for your further analysis and development.

Be aware that this particular LeetCode question is marked as "Hard". Seeing your code attempt, and the quite fundamental shortcomings in it, I really think you should practice coding with trees from a good book (or other reliable sources). Then you could decide to tackle some "Easy" and "Medium" challenges that relate to trees, and only then I would return to this one.

Comment: Thanks for your words of encouragement!

Comment: Happy coding! Does the `to_binary_tree` function solve your issue?

Comment: Yes thanks. I will be using it for an easier question as per your advice.